# git clone vim and make occurs error message

Tags: git, vim

First, I'm following instructions here: https://www.vim.org/git.php

I got git clone of vim and go to directory vim/src and typed make, I got this error message:

```
no terminal library found
checking for tgetent()... configure: error: NOT FOUND!
      You need to install a terminal library; for example ncurses.
      Or specify the name of the library with --with-tlib.
Makefile:2046: recipe for target 'auto/config.mk' failed
make: *** [auto/config.mk] Error 1
```

I didn't make changes so I didn't take  step like "git pull" "git stash" ....

Comment: You are missing some dependencies, see the respective README file, e.g. `README_unix.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to install a missing dependencie : [ncurses](/questions/tagged/ncurses) :

For debian/ubuntu based distros: `# apt install ncurses-base`

For redhat/centos: `# yum install ncurses`